# Create a new column with null column names in pl sql

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to display a column with null value columns names in procedure. 
Every help will be highly appreciated.

```
 Procedure ** IS     
     result varchar2(100);
  cursor a
     IS 
       select 
             A,
             B,
             C,
              CASE B is null then 'B' else '' end result
     from table
             where A is null or B is null or C is null 
    Begin 
            ........ 
    END;
```

I need to include in result variable if the column A and C has null values for a particular record.

Excepted Result

```
A   |  B  | C   |  Result
--  | ----| ----|  -----
1   | null| 1   |    B
null| 2   | null|  A C
```

Comment: Please show some sample data.

Comment: I could get one column using case .but looking for more number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

DECODE can be used to display if both col A and C have null values a follows:

```
DECODE(A, NULL, DECODE(C, NULL, 'A and C are NULL', ''), '')
```

Comment: what happens if i have 10 columns .

Comment: You will have to list out the 10 columns either using DECODE or NVL2. If it's a check to see if all columns are null for a particular row then you could create a routine that returns a cursor by using all_tab_cols and generating a dynamic sql.